# How to move iTunes library from High Sierra Mac to Monterey Mac

Tags: itunes, migration, monterey, music.app

I'm setting up a Mac for someone who previously had files scattered across several separate computers. I upgraded the destination to Monterey and have been copying over files successfully.

Now I'm dealing with iTunes. She had her iTunes library on a Mac running High Sierra. I copied over the iTunes folder into ~/Music on the new Mac. It looks like I can't just tell Music (app) to use the iTunes folder. I tried selecting that folder (preferences/files) and her music didn't magically appear inside Music (app).

Is there another way to do this? Do I need to "import" in Music to pull her music in? If I do that does it create copies of the music files? This is important at present because she's got about 80GB of music and only 50GB of space left on the new Mac (for now - I plan to clear out more space).

Thanks in advance for any advice or suggestions.

Bob

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-10831